# RuntimeError: Not compiled with GPU support

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to run a code and I got the error:
`RuntimeError: Not compiled with GPU support`

I searched around and realized it might be that my CUDA version has some issues.
I installed the newest CUDA 11.5 first and then I realized that pytorch doesn't support that version so I uninstalled CUDA 11.5 and reinstall CUDA 10.2
I already deleted everything that is related to CUDA 11.5 but when I run

`python -c 'import torch; from torch.utils.cpp_extension import CUDA_HOME; print(torch.cuda.is_available(), CUDA_HOME)'`

I still get `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5`
instead of `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2`

I already went to the directory `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA` to manually delete v11.5 but the CUDA_HOME doesn't change.

Any idea how to manually change the CUDA_HOME? Is there a way to delete CUDA 11.5 completely since I only want to keep CUDA 10.2

Comment: "RuntimeError: Not compiled with GPU support" is a pretty straightforward error. You don't have a CUDA enabled torch build and nothing you do short of changing to a different build which is CUDA enabled will change things. This has nothing to do with what version of CUDA you have installed or what paths you do or do not set

Comment: To change CUDA_HOME, in the command line (or .bashrc file) export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

Answer (score -2):

It seems your cuda enabled pytorch version is not installed in the directory you are working in. Simply, using command line type following command, you can confirm it. It might help you

import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()

> > > True

If it is false, please install pytorch having enabled cuda using this link
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
for example, for Linux

conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch